# DuendeSoftware IdentityServer how to customize usage

Tags: c#, api, microservices, identityserver4, duende-identity-server

We are using microservices in our application. For the authentication we are checking DuendeSoftware IdentityServer (.Net 6).
Could you please let me know if below requirements can be achieved?

1. Single login API
2. Use our own login model, only API login is required
3. If IdentityServer host is restarted, current logged in users should not be affected (planning hosting in azure). i.e.Survives server restarts and app deployments.
4. Should not use local memory

I went through their official documents https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6 and tried few samples. It would be helpful if I get some experts suggestions on proceeding further

Comment: That's a commercial product.  Why not just **ask** them about your needs.